# How to write an rspec test to properly check that an image has been rendered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm writing tests for email for my Rails app, but I can't figure out how to test that an image has been properly included in the email. I've tried have_content, and have_tag, and also Googled everywhere, but can't seem to find an appropriate method.

There has to be some straightforward way to test this, unless I'm missing something.

This is what I have so far...

```
describe "registration email" do
  it "has the right logo image" do
    email.body.should have_tag("img[src='www.mysite.com/assets/logo.png']")
  end
end
```

But getting this error:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `has_tag?' for :Mail::Body
```